# Angular UI Router - allow ANY query string parameter

Tags: angular-ui-router

I am using the Angular UI Router and this works well in most situations. However, I have a situation where I don't know the names of the query string parameters ahead of time.

So normally with UI router you would define a route something like this:

```js
$stateProvider.state('test', {
 url: '/test?testQueryStringParam',
 templateUrl: 'Test.html',
 controller: 'TestController'
});
```

Then in my controller I can access the testQueryStringParam using $stateParams.

However, with UI router you can't access any query string parameters not specified in the route definition.

The router that comes with the Angular framework, does allow you to do this. So I have tried using the $location service with my UI router defintion. This does sort of work.

When I want to add a query string parameter I use:

```js
$location.search("paramName", "paramValue");
```

When I want to get the query string values I just use:

```js
$location.search()
```

This updates the URL, but doesn't re-instantiate the controller (like $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}) would). This doesn't seem like a big problem because I can just re-load the data myself. However, if you use the back button in the browser, again it changes the URL, but doesn't re-instantiate the controller.

Is there anyway

1. I can get this to work using just the UI Router?
2. Get the workaround of using $location to actually re-instantiate the controller.?

As a last resort I also tried directing updating the window.location, but this refreshes the entire page which isn't acceptable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass non url parameters that do not appear in URL

```
$stateProvider.state('test', {
    url: '/test?testQueryStringParam',
    params: {
    optParam: null,
    },
    templateUrl: 'Test.html',
    controller: 'TestController'
});
```

As you can see, `optParam` is an optional parameter with a default value of null and will not be visible in the URL

You can access this param in your controller  using `$stateParams`

```
$stateParams.optParam
```

Here is a helpful [blog](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters)