# Non-registered QueryParams getting stripped away on $state.transitionTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state configuration of the below sorts:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myModule')

    .config(function($stateProvider, 'root', 'place-locator') {

      var placeLocatorConfig = {
        url: '/place-locator/{param1}/{param2}?qp1&qp2',
        parent: 'root',
        params: {
          param1: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
          },
          param2: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
          }
        },
        views: {
          main: {
            templateUrl: 'app/placeLocator/placeLocator.tpl.html',
            controller: 'PlaceLocatorController as vm',
            bindings: {
              places: '='
            }
          }
        }
      };

      $stateProvider
        .state('place-locator', placeLocatorConfig);

    });

})(angular);
```

Whenever I try to `$state.transitionTo` a child state, it all works fine as long as the QueryParams in the URLs are the ones that are registered in the StateConfig(i.e. `qp1` or `qp2`).

But as soon as the URL contains a queryParam that is not registered in the configuration(say `qp3`), it gets stripped away on `$state.transitionTo`

Now, I'm not really sure what the names of these QueryParams are going to be. But I still need them in the URL after `$state.transitionTo`.

How do I achieve this without registering them as a part of the StateConfig?

I had a look at the below questions:

[Adding query string to UI router route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926017/adding-query-string-to-ui-router-route)

[Angular UI Router - allow ANY query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449774/angular-ui-router-allow-any-query-string-parameter)

[Query string parameter in ui-router urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461714/query-string-parameter-in-ui-router-urls)

But none of them resembles my case.

I've also tried the solution in this case:

[AngularJS UI-Router navigate without removing query params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097469/angularjs-ui-router-navigate-without-removing-query-params)

But that doesn't help. The non-registered QueryParams are still getting stripped away.

Comment: Do you REALLY nead them in url? Is it about external link or your internal state transitions?

Comment: Yeah. It's because these are queryParams related to Google Analytics tracking. So things like `icid` would be a part of the queryParams and we don't really know the names of all the queryParams there would be upfront. Also the names of these queryParams might change in the future and we don't want to change our route config file every time the names change. So.

And it's about interal state transitions.